# Unable to import create_pandas_dataframe_agent due to langchain_core and langchain relative path issues

Tags: python, pandas, langchain

I am trying to import `create_pandas_dataframe_agent` from `langchain.agents` (in Databricks), and I am getting the following strange error:

```
from langchain.agents import AgentType
```

```
ValueError: '<path_name>/python3.0/site-packages/langchain/agents' is not in the subpath of '<path_name>/python3.0/site-packages/langchain_core' OR one path is relative and the other is absolute
```

I updated both langchain_core and langchain to the latest versions, but the error is still there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe ask on  `langchain` github - ie. [ImportError: cannot import name 'AgentType' from 'langchain.agents' · Issue #7613 · langchain-ai/langchain](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/7613)

Comment: error shows `python3.0` - it is very, very old version. Maybe it needs to install newer `Python` ie. `3.11` (`3.12` may be too fresh)  and install the newest `langchain`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Python 3.10. What helped me was uninstalling langchain and installing the latest version, 0.0.350. Then, I installed langchain-experimental and changed the import statement to 'from langchain_experimental.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent'.

```
pip uninstall langchain
pip install langchain
pip install langchain_experimental
```

Then in code:

```
from langchain_experimental.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

> 1. langchain_experimental version is 0.0.42 .
> 2. python version is 3.11.
> 3. langchain version is 0.0.42.

And here is my code to import.

```
from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
```

Link to documents: https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/pandas